# clip-path not working in SVG sprite

Tags: svg

(live example at http://codepen.io/RwwL/pen/xbNLJp)

I'm including SVGs in an app using the `<symbol>` element (see https://css-tricks.com/svg-symbol-good-choice-icons/ for full details as to why), and certain icons — ones that include `clip-path` — are not rendering when I include their icons in pages with the `<use>` element.

```
<svg style="display: none">
  <symbol id="icon-pin" viewBox="0 0 24 24" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24">
    <path fill="none" stroke="#2F3137" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M12 2C8.3 2 5.3 5 5.3 8.7c0 1.2.3 2.3.9 3.3l5.4 9.9c.1.1.2.2.4.2.1 0 .3-.1.4-.2l5.4-9.9c.5-.9.9-2.1.9-3.3C18.7 5 15.7 2 12 2zm0 0" />
    <clipPath id="pin-clip">
        <path d="M12 11.2c-1.4 0-2.5-1.1-2.5-2.5s1.1-2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.1 2.5 2.5-1.1 2.5-2.5 2.5zm0 0" />
    </clipPath>
    <path clip-path="url(#pin-clip)" fill="#2F3137" d="M4.5 1.2h15v15h-15z" />
  </symbol>
</svg>
</div>

<h2>Normal inline SVG</h2>
<svg id="inlinePin" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 24 24" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24">
    <path fill="none" stroke="#2F3137" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M12 2C8.3 2 5.3 5 5.3 8.7c0 1.2.3 2.3.9 3.3l5.4 9.9c.1.1.2.2.4.2.1 0 .3-.1.4-.2l5.4-9.9c.5-.9.9-2.1.9-3.3C18.7 5 15.7 2 12 2zm0 0" />
    <clipPath id="inline-pin-clip">
        <path d="M12 11.2c-1.4 0-2.5-1.1-2.5-2.5s1.1-2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.1 2.5 2.5-1.1 2.5-2.5 2.5zm0 0" />
    </clipPath>
    <path clip-path="url(#inline-pin-clip)" fill="#2F3137" d="M4.5 1.2h15v15h-15z" />
</svg>

<h2>Inline SVG using sprite</h2>
<svg>
  <use xlink:href="#icon-pin">
</svg>
```

Here's how it's rendering:

[image]

It's broken in the same way across Chrome/Firefox/Safari, so it seems to most likely just be something I'm not understanding about the way other elements need to be referenced in SVG, especially when a `symbol` is being pulled in via a `use`. IE11 is also not rendering correctly, but in a slightly different way (no dot in the middle of the pin, but no solid square box like the others).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is caused by the very first line

```
<svg style="display: none">
```

Removing `display: none` will render your svg referencing the inline sprite just fine.

This does at first seem a bit odd since the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#SymbolElement) tells us

> The ‘display’ property does not apply to the ‘symbol’ element; thus,
>   ‘symbol’ elements are not directly rendered even if the ‘display’
>   property is set to a value other than none, and ‘symbol’ elements are
>   available for referencing even when the ‘display’ property on the
>   ‘symbol’ element or any of its ancestors is set to none.

But reading [further down](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#DisplayProperty) the spec it becomes apparent why setting `display: none` causes this unexpected rendering:

> The ‘display’ property affects direct rendering into offscreen
>   canvases also [...] Setting display: none on a child of a
>   ‘clipPath’ element will prevent the given child element from
>   contributing to the clipping path.

Thus, setting `display: none` globally on the `svg` inhibits rendering of these *offscreen canvases* leaving you with the incomplete clip path, although it can still be referenced. Removing the `display`-attribute from the root `svg` and setting it directly to the `clipPath` will demonstrate the same behaviour.

To hide your sprite svg you could go for something like

```
<svg width="0" height="0">
```

#### Update:

IE and Firefox seem to be even a bit more stringent on rendering the *offscreen canvases* when putting a `clipPath` inside a symbol. Since symbols itself are never rendered, the contained `clipPath` will keep missing the offscreen rendering and can therefore not meaningfully be applied to any element. You should put the `clipPath` right outside the symbol which works well in IE, FF and Chrome.

```
<svg>
    <clipPath id="pin-clip">
        <path d="M12 11.2c-1.4 0-2.5-1.1-2.5-2.5s1.1-2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.1 2.5 2.5-1.1 2.5-2.5 2.5zm0 0" />
    </clipPath>
    <symbol id="icon-pin" viewBox="0 0 24 24" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24">
        <path fill="none" stroke="#2F3137" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M12 2C8.3 2 5.3 5 5.3 8.7c0 1.2.3 2.3.9 3.3l5.4 9.9c.1.1.2.2.4.2.1 0 .3-.1.4-.2l5.4-9.9c.5-.9.9-2.1.9-3.3C18.7 5 15.7 2 12 2zm0 0" />
        <path clip-path="url(#pin-clip)" fill="#2F3137" d="M4.5 1.2h15v15h-15z" />
    </symbol>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, very interesting solution. Removing display: none fixed this fine in Chrome/Firefox/Safari, but IE10/11 are still exhibiting the same issue; any idea why that is?

Comment: IE and FF seem to be more stringent on this. I have incorporated an update in my answer dealing with IE, FF and Chrome.

Comment: Brilliant. Here's the cross-browser solution fork of the original pen: http://codepen.io/RwwL/pen/GgaGgV  Thanks a ton! It'll be a pain to restructure a handful of the icons in our library, but at least it'll work... Thanks again!

Comment: As for Chrome 48.0.2564.116 (64-bit) on march 21, 2016 seems to work for inlined SVG's only :(

Comment: As opposed to *what*? Could you provide a demo showing the problem you experienced?