# Hiding an SVG element in HTML without disabling clip paths defined inside?

Tags: html, css, svg

With reference to the question [clip-path not working in SVG sprite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29480607/clip-path-not-working-in-svg-sprite), it seems we can't use `style="display:none"` to hide an SVG element that defines a clip path that will be used elsewhere.

However, the suggested alternative for hiding it given (using `width="0" height="0"`) is not working for me (at least in Chrome, the SVG element still gets allocated space in the page layout, which causes a vertical scroll bar to appear, as I have a div with `height="100%"` above it).  What other was are available for hiding an SVG that won't stop it being used for clipping?

Comment: how about using position: absolute and then position it off the page somewhere

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing, but it seems very much like a hack.  But both `display: none` and `visibility: hidden` break the clipping (in different ways), so I can't see a better way as of right now.  It just seems odd that there's no way to define an object such that it doesn't have an actual position but can still be referenced by other objects...

Comment: Did you use `style="width:0;height:0;"`? For me, `width="0" height="0"` as XML attributes works fine for both FF and Chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end, I used `position:absolute` to take the item out of the usual HTML document flow.  I don't understand why a zero-sized element would cause scrollbars to appear, but that certainly seemed to be what was happening.