# Provide an SVG filter without an actual svg element

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an `svg` only to provide a filter for an `img`:

```
<svg>
    <filter id="makewhite">
        <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 1  0 0 0 0 1  0 0 0 0 1  0 0 0 1 0" />
    </filter>
</svg>

<img src="icon.svg" style="filter:url(#makewhite)">
```

This content-less SVG still has a size and pushes my content aside:

[image: size]

Is there a better way to provide a filter to an SVG `img`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove or hide svg element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24578837/remove-or-hide-svg-element)

Comment: Or maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/44485500/1427878

Comment: The second one only has one (horrible) answer, but the first one suggests to use `display: none;`. If that is the preferred way, then go ahead and add it as an answer.

Comment: That answer isn’t as horrible as you might think; there are certain situations where hiding stuff via a simple `display: none` can have adverse effects. For example if stuff needs to be hidden from view, but still be available to screen readers - then using absolute positioning (plus some more properties, width and height set to 1px, overflow cut off, ...) is the preferable method. Whether all browsers will let you apply the filter if the SVG is actually hidden using display:none is something you’ll have to test.

Comment: It's horrible because it contains "In the end, I ..." and no "because".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there absolutely is. You can inline the SVG file as data: URL and then load it using `url()` function.

```css
filter: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><filter id="makewhite"><feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 1  0 0 0 0 1  0 0 0 0 1  0 0 0 1 0"/></filter></svg>#makewhite');
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid `display: none` as a general rule. It affects the rendering of some elements, so we usually don't recommend that.

You can just use `width="0" height="0"`.

If you wish, you could also add `style="position: absolute;"` or `"opacity: 0"` if you want, but they shouldn't be necessary.